# Selectify select

Tags: jquery, select

how add options to Selectify select in jquery?

```
$.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : ''+site_url+'ajax.php?city_ajax',
            dataType : 'json', 
            data : {'ostan' : $(elm).val() },
            success : function(data) {
                if(data == null) return false; 
                    html = '';
                    for(x in data.id) {
                        html += '<option value="'+data.id[x]+'">'+data.title[x]+'</option>';
                    }
                    $("select[name='cityid']").html('<option value="">city</option>'+html);
                    $("select[name='cityid']").selectify();
                }
        });
```

with this code my select just has one option.

Comment: Are you certain `html` is filled?

Comment: yes, html value is:
<option value="">city</option><option value="61">city1</option><option value="62"> city2</option><option value="64"> city3</option>

Comment: Please use a more meaningful title for your question!

Answer (score 0):

I tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w1b7b6qe/). Seems to work, Are you really sure your `html` variable is filled?

Where have you placed your `.ajax` call? Are you certain it's not overridden elsewhere or called too early?

Try putting it in a `$(document).ready()` block, or delaying it a bit to ensure the DOM is ready to handle your request.